# How BarCode,QR Code are recognized without capturing the image?

Tags: ios, camera, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning

I wonder how Bar Code and QR Code (even character) are recognized without capturing it.I have seen in many app, when we keep our device above any of these (QR/Bar Code), the app automatically recognize it and starts processing. Is there any scanning mechanism used for this? How this can be achieved? What are mechanism involving in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are third party libraries like ZBar in ios which decodes the QRcode/Barcode the developers would have implemented it

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy: Ya I know there are some SDK available.But my doubt is, how this functionalities working?.Either by capturing or without capturing the image?As far as I know, we are doing something like scanning and then processing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  1) The phone camera will be launched by the library it will autofocus and scans until it finds the decoded info from the image displayed by camera

  2) The info will be parsed by the library and it will give you the result.
```

the decoded info is "the bar code which has a information decoded in it"

```
Example for QRCode: The data is present as square 

        for barcode: the data is present as vertical lines
```

The library has all the logics for detecting the type of code and decoding as per the format.
Please read more the QrCode/Bar code libraries docs or implement it and learn

Comment: But in many applications, without clicking the capture button its automatically focus into barcode,picks the barcode alone and starts processing. Are they performing any capturing action in the background.

Comment: Yes it continuously autofocus till it detects the QRCode image or barcode image present in the barcode once it is obtained it captures it and send those data to the library. It autofocus continuously till detects the barcode image if it doesn't find it wont give you any result

Comment: only capturing means? when you say capture it wants to capture the image after the camera is launched

Comment: But still how it detects QR/Bar code before capturing it.How we are getting the input to conclude that camera focussing on QR Code only before capturing it?My doubt is, how our camera recognize that focusing one is Bar code or some other?

Comment: the camera itself is been inited by the ZBar library oly it will read the image which seen in the camera view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28493/discussion-between-nsuserdefault-and-lochana-ragupathy)

Comment: its better to ask the author of those QR/Bar Code Libraries !!,.

Comment: Ho great... I have confused myself by mis-understanding the concept.Thank you very much for answering me patiently.

Comment: thank you for your response and do read about the sdk's for better understanding

Comment: I have another doubt, Is there a way to get the image by scanning without capturing it? any scanning process available in ios? I searched a lot.I found nothing.

Comment: just read the sdk's doc's you will find and the camera displays the image on the screen oly it will never save the image anywhere actually it oly scans form the image displayed by the camera. plz read the docs and you have soo many options like inputing a video file etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVCaptureSession`, e.g.:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
var qrPayload: String?

func startSession() {
    guard !started else { return }

    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: .main)

    let device: AVCaptureDevice?

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        device = AVCaptureDevice
            .DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .metadataObject, position: .back)
            .devices
            .first
    } else {
        device = AVCaptureDevice.devices().first { $0.position == .back }
    }

    guard
        let camera = device,
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera),
        session.canAddInput(input),
        session.canAddOutput(output)
    else {
        // handle failures here
        return
    }

    session.addInput(input)

    session.addOutput(output)
    output.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]

    let videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    videoLayer.frame = view.bounds
    videoLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

    view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

    session.startRunning()
}
```

And extend your view controller to conform to `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`:

```
extension QRViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard
            qrPayload == nil,
            let object = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject,
            let string = object.stringValue
        else { return }

        qrPayload = string
        print(qrPayload)

        // perhaps dismiss this view controller now that you’ve succeeded
    }
}
```

Note, I’m testing to make sure that the `qrPayload` is `nil` because I find that you can see `metadataOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` get called a few times before the view controller is dismissed.