# Is there a way I can create a simple iOS camera instance without asking for camera permissions? (Swift 5.1)

Tags: ios, permissions, camera, swift5

Okay, so, I know the title is kinda vague, so let me explain what I want to accomplish:

I’m making an iOS/iPadOS app that doesn’t primarily need access to the device’s camera, but I wanted to add a feature where you can scan a QR code to import certain types of data into an app. Most apps typically do this by using the app permissions to give the app access to the device’s camera, and then they can scan the QR code.

However, I want it to not have to ask for permission because I believe what happens, and feel free to correct me if I’m wrong about what I’m about to explain, is I believe that there are two different types of software camera instances, the system camera, and the application camera. The application camera is what apps need to ask permission for to access the camera and can have wide flexibility in whatever the developer wants to do with it, but I want the system camera, which would be very limited, as the system camera instance is sandboxed and totally separate from your app, and you don’t have much freedom with what you want with it, which is fine, because I just want to scan a QR code, seems simple enough. And then I want iOS to send only the data my app needs from the system camera instance, in this case, the data for a QR code. I don’t need depth info, the location in which it was scanned or anything else, I just want to instruct iOS to only send the data encoded in the QR code to my app.

I’m only asking how to do this since I’ve seen apps that use the camera, but don’t ask for camera permission, so I know it’s possible, and it would be nice to not have to clutter up the camera permissions for such a minor feature in my app.

I’ve already tried to figure this one out myself & researched this, but I can’t seem to find it & maybe I’m just not looking for the right thing. If anyone can help me with this, that’d be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: No, if you want to access the camera, even just for barcode scanning, you need camera permission. You can't ask the system for "barcode data".  You have to obtain a frame from the camera and pass it to the barcode detector yourself.  Since the app has access to the frame data it needs camera permission.

Comment: “I’m only asking how to do this since I’ve seen apps that use the camera, but don’t ask for camera permission” ... I find that surprising, but admittedly older iOS versions were less scrupulous about enforcing various permissions and usage descriptions. Do you have an example of a recently introduced/updated app that uses the camera and doesn't ask for permissions? What version of iOS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you’re taking photos with high-level `UIImagePickerController` or scanning for QR codes using a lower-level `AVCaptureSession` (a great UX for QR scanning, allowing you to quickly scan QR codes [without having to hit a button to recognize the QR code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339649/1271826)), you need to set `NSCameraUsageDescription`.

These usage description strings are our chance to instill confidence in our customers: From the end-user’s perspective, they just see the camera come on and have no assurances about what’s really getting captured and what our app is going to use it for. You may feel it’s obvious, but this alert gives us a chance to be explicit and assuage any user apprehensions about how the resulting photo, video, or metadata object may be used.